# Ignoring hyphens deliberately

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a small utility which can REPLACE some variables to some other format on around 8000 source code files.

For example, I have the following kind of source code written on Progress4GL.
Note: Progress4GL allows to use hyphen in variable names:

```
where x-crudefn.segment-id[5] =crudefn.segment-id[v-idx]
```

I need to find exactly the occurance of `crudefn.segment-id`

When I use the regex `(crudefn.segment-id)(\[)`, it finds it on both parts of equal sign.

In this case, `x-crudefn.segment-id` is another variable, which I DON'T want to replace.

I only want to replace the variable `crudefn.segment-id`

When I try to ignore hyphen using the regex `[^\-](crudefn.segment-id)(\[)`, it also includes the equal sign in the match result`("=crudefn.segment-id[")`, which I don't want. In some cases the source code is like:

```
where x-crudefn.segment-id[5] =crudefn.segment-id[v-idx]
```

and in some other cases it's like this:

`where x-crudefn.segment-id[5] = a + crudefn.segment-id[v-idx]`

Comment: Try [`(?<!-)\bcrudefn\.segment-id\[`](https://regex101.com/r/qQ6zZ8/2)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to match the `crudefn` word as a whole word but excluding  the positions after a hyphen.

You can use

```
(?<!-)\bcrudefn\.segment-id\[
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qQ6zZ8/3)

The `\b` word boundary will make the word `crudefn` match after a non-word character, and the negative lookbehind `(?<!-)` will fail the match if a hyphen appears right in front of this word.

Also, note that a dot must be escaped to match a literal dot (otherwise, it will match any character but a newline.)

In Java,

```
String pattern = "(?<!-)\\bcrudefn\\.segment-id\\[";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look up what constitutes a variable name.
Then construct a regex around it.

I.e. starts with a word, ends with a word, etc...

`(?<![-\w])crudefn\.segment-id(?![-\w])`

This way you don't have to worry about stupid word boundaries
and spurious punctuation.

https://regex101.com/r/qQ6zZ8/4